# How do I make this function more generic?

Tags: jquery, repeat

I have a little jQuery function calculating some inputs. I would like to be able to make this more generic so that I don't have to repeat this code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    update_amounts();
    jQuery('.list_item_9 input:not([readonly])').change(function() {
        update_amounts();
    });
});

function update_amounts() {
    var sum = 0;
    jQuery('.list_item_9 input:not([readonly])').each(function() {
        sum += Number(jQuery(this).val());
    });
    jQuery('.list_item_9 .gfield_list_184_cell5 input').val(sum);
}
```

The HTML for this looks like the following:

```
<tr class="gfield_list_group list_item_9">
    <td class="gfield_list_cell">
        <input type="text" name="FIELDLABEL" value="" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell">
        <input type="text" name="TWO" value="">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell">
        <input type="text" name="THREE" value="">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell">
        <input type="text" name="FOUR" value="">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_184_cell5">
        <input type="text" name="TOTAL" value="0" readonly="">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I've tried multiple iterations of this but I can't quite figure out how to target the function based on what has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you want. Each time an input changes, it finds the parent `gfield_list_group` class element, then sums all the not-readonly inputs below that, writing the total to the input with `name="TOTAL"` (you might want to change that to a class specifier e.g. `glist_total_cell`). For initialisation, there is a routine `update_all_amounts` which sums inputs under all `gfield_list_group` elements.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  update_all_amounts();
  jQuery('.gfield_list_group input:not([readonly])').change(function() {
    update_amounts(jQuery(this));
  });
});

function update_amounts(inp) {
  var sum = 0;
  var parent = inp.closest('.gfield_list_group');
  parent.find('input:not([readonly])').each(function() {
    sum += Number(jQuery(this).val());
  });
  parent.find('input[name="TOTAL"]').val(sum);
}

function update_all_amounts() {
  jQuery('.gfield_list_group').each(function() {
    update_amounts(jQuery(this).find('input:not([readonly])').first());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="gfield_list_group list_item_9">
    <td class="gfield_list_cell">
      <input type="text" name="FIELDLABEL" value="row 9" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell">
      <input type="text" name="TWO" value="">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell">
      <input type="text" name="THREE" value="6">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell">
      <input type="text" name="FOUR" value="">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_184_cell5">
      <input type="text" name="TOTAL" value="0" readonly="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="gfield_list_group list_item_10">
    <td class="gfield_list_cell">
      <input type="text" name="FIELDLABEL" value="row 10" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell">
      <input type="text" name="TWO" value="4">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell">
      <input type="text" name="THREE" value="">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell">
      <input type="text" name="FOUR" value="">
    </td>
    <td class="gfield_list_cell gfield_list_184_cell5">
      <input type="text" name="TOTAL" value="0" readonly="">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The demo below is very generic -- no ids, classes, or attribute selectors -- only `tagNames` are used.

- wrap everything into a `<form>` and delegate "input" or "change" event to it.
- change the `type` of `<input>` to `number`.
- remember to convert each value of an input into a real number before calculations.
- don't use `<input readonly>` instead use `<output></ouput>`

#### Demo

Details are commented in demo

```js
// Delegate the input event to the <form>
$('form').on('input', function(e) {
  // Declare sum at 0
  var sum = 0;
  // On each <input>
  $(this).find('input').each(function() {
    // Convert the value of each input and add it to sum
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });
  // Assign sum to the last <output>
  $('output:last').val(sum);
});
```

```css
form {
  margin: 50px auto
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <output>Name</output>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" value='0'>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" value='0'>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" value='0'>
      </td>
      <td>
        <output>0</output>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```